# Priority Queue using a Max-Heap Data Structure

Tags: python, insert, heap, priority-queue, max-heap

I am implementing a priority queue using a max-heap data structure in Python. I'm using several names that have numbers associated with them as their priority (9 being the highest and 1 being the lowest). The issue I am facing is that when I dequeue an item from the priority queue, it does not dequeue the item with highest priority. I assume this means there is a problem with my enqueue and it is not inserting the items into the correct position in the heap based on their priority. If anyone could help me fix this, it would be greatly appreciated.

My priority queue code:

```
from Heap import Heap

class priorityQ(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.PQ = Heap()

    def enqueue(self, priority, item):
        self.PQ.insert((priority, item))

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.PQ.size() == 0:
            raise ValueError("Empty Queue")
        return self.PQ.delete_max()

    def first(self):
        return self.PQ.get_max()

    def size(self):
        return self.PQ.size()

def main():
    myHeap = priorityQ()
    print(myHeap.size())
    myHeap.enqueue(8, "Kaneda")
    myHeap.enqueue(6, "Masaru")
    myHeap.enqueue(9, "Akira")
    myHeap.enqueue(4, " Kei")
    myHeap.enqueue(5, "Takashi")
    myHeap.enqueue(2, "Shikishima")
    myHeap.enqueue(3, "Kiyoko")
    myHeap.enqueue(1, "Yamagata")
    myHeap.enqueue(7, "Tetsuo")
    print(myHeap.first())
    print(myHeap.size())
    myHeap.dequeue()
    print(myHeap.first())
    print(myHeap.size())
    myHeap.dequeue()
    print(myHeap.first())
    print(myHeap.size())
    myHeap.dequeue()
    print(myHeap.first())
    print(myHeap.size())
    myHeap.dequeue()
    print(myHeap.first())
    print(myHeap.size())
    myHeap.dequeue()
    print(myHeap.first())
    print(myHeap.size())
    myHeap.dequeue()
    print(myHeap.first())
    print(myHeap.size())
    myHeap.dequeue()
    print(myHeap.first())
    print(myHeap.size())
    myHeap.dequeue()
    print(myHeap.first())
    print(myHeap.size())
    myHeap.dequeue()
    print(myHeap.first())
    print(myHeap.size())
```

Output after I run the code and call main:

```
0
(9, 'Akira')
9
(7, 'Tetsuo')
8
(5, 'Takashi')
7
(4, 'Kei')
6
(3, 'Kiyoko')
5
(2, 'Shikishima')
4
(1, 'Yamagata')
3
(1, 'Yamagata')
2
(1, 'Yamagata')
1
None
0
```

Max-heap code (provided by textbook):

```
# Heap.py
class Heap(object):

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def __init__(self, items=None):

        '''post: a heap is created with specified items'''

        self.heap = [None]
        if items is None:
            self.heap_size = 0
        else:
            self.heap += items
            self.heap_size = len(items)
            self._build_heap()

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def size(self):

        '''post: returns number of items in the heap'''

        return self.heap_size

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def _heapify(self, position):

        '''pre: items from 0 to position - 1 satisfy the heap property
        post: heap property is satisfied for the entire heap'''

        item = self.heap[position]
        while position * 2 <= self.heap_size:
            child = position * 2
            # if right child, determine maximum of two children
            if (child != self.heap_size and 
                self.heap[child+1] > self.heap[child]):
                child += 1
            if self.heap[child] > item:
                self.heap[position] = self.heap[child]
                position = child
            else:
                break
        self.heap[position] = item

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def delete_max(self):

        '''pre: heap property is satisfied
        post: maximum element in heap is removed and returned'''

        if self.heap_size > 0:
            max_item = self.heap[1]
            self.heap[1] = self.heap[self.heap_size]
            self.heap_size -= 1
            self.heap.pop()
            if self.heap_size > 0:
                self._heapify(1)
            return max_item

    def get_max(self):
        if self.heap_size > 0:
            max_item = self.heap[1]
            self.heap[1] = self.heap[self.heap_size]
            if self.heap_size > 0:
                self._heapify(1)
            return max_item

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def insert(self, item):

        '''pre: heap property is satisfied
        post: item is inserted in proper location in heap'''

        self.heap_size += 1
        # extend the length of the list
        self.heap.append(None)
        position = self.heap_size
        parent = position // 2
        while parent > 0 and self.heap[parent] < item:
            # move item down
            self.heap[position] = self.heap[parent]
            position = parent
            parent = position // 2
        # put new item in correct spot
        self.heap[position] = item

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def _build_heap(self):

        '''pre: self.heap has values in 1 to self.heap_size 
        post: heap property is satisfied for entire heap'''

        # 1 through self.heap_size
        for i in range(self.heap_size // 2, 0, -1): # stops at 1
            self._heapify(i)

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def heapsort(self):

        '''pre: heap property is satisfied
        post: items are sorted in self.heap[1:self.sorted_size]'''

        sorted_size = self.heap_size
        for i in range(0, sorted_size - 1):
            # Since delete_max calls pop to remove an item, we need 
            # to append a dummy value to avoid an illegal index.
            self.heap.append(None)
            item = self.delete_max()
            self.heap[sorted_size - i] = item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be in your enqueue.

```
def enqueue(self, item, priority):
        self.PQ.insert(item)
```

The priority parameter is not used at all. Instead, your heap is using string comparisons.

This is the state of your heap before any dequeue:

```
[None, 'Yamagata', 'Tetsuo', 'Shikishima', 'Takashi', 'Masaru', 'Akira', 'Kiyoko', 'Kei', 'Kaneda']
```

Comment: Ah, I see. How could I changed my code to use that parameter? Would I need to change the code for insert in the Heap class?

Comment: @coleworld You would first have to make sure that items stored in the Heap is associated with a priority. Then you would want to modify insert so that the comparison is made between the priority of items, as opposed to the items themselves.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. So I changed my code above to reflect the changes I made. In my enqueue function, I made a tuple of (priority, item) to be passed through insert as the item. This way each string is associated with a priority. This seemed to do the trick as it did dequeue the item with highest priority first (9, 'Akira') but then it skips 8 and 6 and 1 is repeated three times. I have been working on changing my insert but everything I have done has either mixed up the order things are dequeued or broken the program. I am extremely confused as to how I would go about this..

Comment: I tried indexing to compare priorities of the item being passed through and its' parent. In my insert function, I created and set parentItem = self.heap[parent] and changed the while statement to (while parent > 0 and item[0] > parentItem[0]:) but that didn't work.

Comment: @coleworld Manually check your heap after you do the inserts. You will find that the insert method works as intended. Now with that said, your problem is neither with your insert nor your delete. Your problem is actually with your get_max method. In a standard implementation of a Heap, get_max should simply return self.heap[1] and that's it (Assuming heap is not empty). However, your implementation also does other stuff that it shouldn't be doing.